# Stop typing in hindi using css

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, language-translation

As a user I want to disabled hindi typing in inputs using csss, is there any way to do the same?

I am using Angular Internationalization
SRC: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview

Comment: Why would you want to do this "as the user"? Surely as the developer?

Comment: As this is giving some backend issues for me

Answer (score 0):

Asfar as I am aware you can set the `lang` attribute to a language for meta information, but it is impossible to enforce disabling hindi in just html & css.